# Extract 3 first bits from [u8; 16] and convert to u32

Tags: rust

So what im trying to do is to mask out the 3 first bits from a byte array and return a u32 from these bits.

I am beginner at Rust and this is what i have done and it works, but i feel there has to be a more elegant way.

```
fn bits_to_u32(input: &[u8; 16]) -> u32 {

    let mask: u8 = 0b0000_0111;
    let masked_out_value: u8 = &input[0].clone() & mask;
    let value = u32::from_le_bytes([masked_out_value, 0, 0, 0]);

    value
}
```

Any suggestions how to make this more elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simplify it to:

```
const LOW_3_BITS_MASK: u8 = 0b0000_0111;

fn bits_to_u32(input: &[u8; 16]) -> u32 {
    u32::from(input[0] & LOW_3_BITS_MASK)
}
```